# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES with OWN .apk

Tags: android

Since I updated my Android Studio, I cant install my App anymore, neither in the debug nor in the release mode.

I always get the error:

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.myappdomain.mypp
```

Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]

Installation failed since the APK was either not signed, or signed incorrectly.
If this is a Gradle-based project, then make sure the signing configuration is specified in the Gradle build script.
Error while Installing APK

From what I googled, this just happens when trying to install unsigned third party .apk
This is my own App though, signed with Android Studio

Gradle looks like this:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("...")
            keyAlias "..."
            storePassword "..."
            keyPassword "..."
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId '...'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing anything with signingConfig in build.gradle? Do you have a prev version of the app installed on your device?

Comment: added my gradle, actually did everything like described in the guides

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by updating the target SDK to 23 and updating all my used libraries. Maybe it helps you too.

Comment: For me turning on "Instant Run" caused this. Fixed by disabling it.